# Oracle get UNIQUE constraint violation error too late

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

What should I check why Oracle server takes more then 20 sec to return `UNIQUE` constraint violation error for specific data?

One of our processes is processing over 30000 data one day with multi process and some time gets UNIQUE constraint violation error in 1 sec

but it takes more then 20 sec to return `UNIQUE` constraint violation error for specific data.

Query is same as below. (Modified only table name)

```
MERGE  
INTO  TableA S
USING (
SELECT NVL(:sccm_cd , ' ') SCCM_CD
 , NVL(:oder_dt , ' ') ODER_DT
 , NVL(:mrkt_dstn_cd, ' ') MRKT_DSTN_CD
 , NVL(:oder_no , ' ') ODER_NO
 , NVL(:cncd_unpr , 0) CNCD_UNPR
 , B.SLBY_FEE_GRD_CD
 , B.ACCT_MNGR_EMPL_NO
 , C.AO_FEE_GRD_CD
  FROM DUAL A
 , TableB B
 , TableC C
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND B.SCCM_CD = :sccm_cd
   AND B.ACNO = :acno
   AND C.SCCM_CD(+) = B.SCCM_CD
   AND C.EMPL_NO(+) = B.ACCT_MNGR_EMPL_NO 
      ) T
ON (     S.sccm_cd       = T.sccm_cd
     AND S.oder_dt         = T.oder_dt
     AND S.mrkt_dstn_cd = T.mrkt_dstn_cd 
     AND S.oder_no        = T.oder_no
     AND S.cncd_unpr     = T.cncd_unpr 
     )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE 
     SET S.cncd_qty       = S.cncd_qty       + NVL(:cncd_qty     ,0)
           , S.slby_fee        = S.slby_fee        + NVL(:slby_fee      ,0)
           , S.slby_fee_srtx = S.slby_fee_srtx + NVL(:slby_fee_srtx,0)
           , S.idx_fee_amt   = S.idx_fee_amt   + NVL(:idx_fee_amt ,0)
           , S.cltr_fee          = S.cltr_fee         + NVL(:cltr_fee        ,0)
           , S.trtx                = S.trtx               + NVL(:trtx             ,0)     
           , S.otc_fee        = S.otc_fee               + NVL(:otc_fee             ,0)     
           , S.wht_fee       = S.wht_fee               + NVL(:wht_fee             ,0)                                   
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (
              sccm_cd
        , oder_dt
        , mrkt_dstn_cd
        , oder_no
        , cncd_unpr
        , acno
        , item_cd
        , slby_dstn_cd
        , md_dstn_cd
        , cncd_qty
        , stlm_dt
        , trtx_txtn_dstn_cd
        , proc_cmpl_dstn_cd
        , item_dstn_cd
        , slby_fee_grd_cd
        , slby_fee
        , slby_fee_srtx
        , idx_fee_amt
        , cltr_fee
        , trtx     
        , wht_fee        
        , otc_fee
            , acct_mngr_empl_no
            , ao_fee_grd_cd
            
        )
        VALUES
        (     T.sccm_cd
            , T.oder_dt
            , T.mrkt_dstn_cd
            , T.oder_no
            , T.cncd_unpr
            , :acno
            , :item_cd
            , :slby_dstn_cd
            , :md_dstn_cd
            , NVL(:cncd_qty     ,0) 
            , DECODE(:mrkt_dstn_cd, 'TN', T.oder_dt, :stlm_dt)
            , :trtx_txtn_dstn_cd
            , '0'
            , :item_dstn_cd
            , NVL(:slby_fee_grd_cd, T.SLBY_FEE_GRD_CD)
            , NVL(:slby_fee        ,0)
            , NVL(:slby_fee_srtx ,0)
            , NVL(:idx_fee_amt   ,0)
            , NVL(:cltr_fee          ,0)
            , NVL(:trtx                ,0)
            , NVL(:wht_fee     , 0)                        
            , NVL(:otc_fee    , 0)
            , T.acct_mngr_empl_no
            , T.ao_fee_grd_cd
            
          )
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what "1 second" and "20 seconds" are measuring here.  The time between when the client sends the `merge` statement to the database and the time the database responds with the unique constraint violation error?  If so, what is the session waiting on during that time period?  My guess would be that the session is blocked waiting for another session that has locked the row it is trying to update and it takes 20 seconds for that other session to commit or rollback its changes.

Comment: When it takes longer, I'd guess that you have a chain of sessions each blocked on the other (i.e. A blocked by B blocked by C blocked by D) that takes more time to resolve.

Comment: @JustinCave ah....I got it I will check deeply it based on your advice :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for it. I will list here some of the possible causes for this behavior.

## Concurrency issue

Your `insert` might be waiting for other operations, like other inserts or updated or deletions.

## Network issues

It is possible that for some reason your network is overwhelmed with requests or, if the server is remote, this could be an internet speed issue as well.

## Server load

The server might be overwhelmed with lots of jobs to do.

## Slow query

It's also possible that the `select` you use in your `insert` command is very slow. It would make sense to test its speed. Also, it would make sense to test `insert` speed as well.